# Explicit wait is not working in selenium webdriver 2.37?

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a method which waits explicitly until the element exists. It was working fine until I upgraded my driver to 2.37. The problem is even though I pass timeout parameter in my method, it doesn't seem to wait that long, instead it throws the "elementNotFound" exception. I believe it is still using the default webdriver's timeout. Below is the code I am using in my method ( this is not my original code, I grabbed it from stackoverflow). I even tried TimeSpanFromMInutes and it doesn't seem to wait that long. Has something got broken in 2.37?

```
public static IWebElement FindElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
    {
        if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
            wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));
            return wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(by));
        }
        return driver.FindElement(by);
    }`
```

Comment: You should debug it. Put a breakpoint in the `if` and ensure it's hitting it. You also should not need to ignore any exception types, it's done for you. Also, does the driver have any implicit wait set?

Comment: I did debug and yes, it reached inside the if statement but it just didn't wait long enough as defined in the timeout parameter. It looks like a bug as Until(ExpectedConditions) works perfectly.IT is the same code that was running for at least 3-4 months and suddenly the upgrade to 2.37 broke it.

Comment: That code didn't change in v2.37: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/dotnet/CHANGELOG ....the expected condition you are using does the *exact same thing* as your initial code: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/dotnet/src/support/UI/ExpectedConditions.cs ....

Comment: Hi @Arran could you please explain how does the implicit wait affect the explicit wait? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say why it stopped working, but you could use ExpectedConditions to see if the element exists.  I tested that and it seems to be working in 2.37:

```
if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
{
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
    wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException)); 
    return wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(by));
}
return driver.FindElement(by);
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, ExpectedConditions seems to be working. At least, it seems to be waiting till the timeout. Is this problem need to be reported to the Selenium community?